# Getting list of all tickers ever in NYSE and NASDAQ

Tags: market-data, historical-data, nyse

Is it possible to obtain a list of all of the stock tickers that have ever been used in both NYSE and NASDAQ? I have tried searching the web and might have a potential solution with Mathematica's `FinancialData` package, but I am not sure if this is the best solution. For those who are curious, I am generating a list of NYSE stocks in Mathematica using

```
FinancialData["NYSE:*", "Lookup"]]
```

The length of this list is 6,494 while the current estimate for the number of actively traded stocks in the NYSE is 2,400, so maybe this is what I am looking for, but this might include various other financial instruments beyond just stocks.

I feel like this should be an easily accessible data set, but I have had no luck.

Comment: Tickers are a nightmare to work with in a historical settings. They are not unique i.e. they are sometimes recycled to designate a different company. Serious research uses permno or cusip, not ticker.

Comment: Got it, I'll look into use either of these instead, thanks @nbbo2